# Selecting element attributes using boolean operators (and, or, not) in XQuery

Tags: xquery, boolean-logic

I want to filter the results of the following XQuery:

```
for $units in $data//*[@id = $ids and (@xref = $a or @xref = $b)]/@id
```

How do I select the elements with a matching **@id** value and and an **@xref** attribute that matches *either* $a or $b, but *not* both $a and $b.

Both $a and $b are node sets with tokenized values, which both act as identifiers. The wanted identifier may be stored in either $a or $b.

My intention is that if $a matches the **@xref** attribute, the query does not check for $b.

Comment: But with that intention you could just use or, couldn't you?  If $a matches the @xref attribute, and does not check $b, it would accept? If $a does not match, it would check $b and accept then. Which is or.

Comment: That's right. I had the problem of selecting too many attributes, but the reason was actually an extra slash elsewhere in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to use xor. Too bad there is no xor...

But != and ne does the same:

```
 for $units in $data//*[@id = $ids and ((@xref = $a) ne (@xref = $b))]/@id
```

And it should be faster to use eq instead of =, for single values:

```
 for $units in $data//*[@id = $ids and ((@xref eq $a) ne (@xref eq $b))]/@id
```

Comment: Beni, we don't know what the type of `$a` and `$b` is. Any of these may be a node-set. Therefore, the suggestion to use `eq` is not correct.

Comment: Indeed, both $a and $b are node sets, which function as additional identifiers.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: But that's why I wrote "for single values". If he has node-sets he should know that these are not single values...

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out and revised the question accordingly.